# Laravel Monolog file permission denied (Not permission issue)

Tags: laravel

Recently I'm made some unit tests on a project, and met the "Failed to open stream: Permission denied" from monolog. It's on a Windows box, and unit test doesn't involve any server side thingy, so I've made a dive on it and made sure it's not file permission issue. After reading some codes, I've found:

1. It's a `LogManager` singleton behind the `log` facade;
2. The [`resolve()` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6e4ecc7e2e67ba36eca325ff49adc55e93a72eb7/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php#L207) doesn't implement any kind of caching;
3. It ends up [creating a new `Monolog` instance](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6e4ecc7e2e67ba36eca325ff49adc55e93a72eb7/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php#L291) every time a log method is called;
4. The above in turn creates a new `StreamHandler`, which calls `fopen` on the log file;
5. The `LogManager` closes the its `stream` on the log file inside destructor.

While tracing, I've seen that successive log method calls occur before previous monolog instance destructure, making the `fopen` on the same file fails.

Anyone has a clue on fixing this? Am I doing anything wrong or something?

Comment: Just got a lead. The log file is supposed to be deleted in `tearDown()`, and it does. Both `file_exists` and `assertFileDoesNotExist` says the file is gone. However, the file can be seen in File Explorer, although couldn't be opened, and system reports nothing is locking the file. I couldn't find out anything holding onto the file, it just sits there and every program seem to treat it as deleted, except File Explorer. I'm suspecting low level system caching stuff...